# How to change every char in string into new char?

Tags: java

For example letter "a". i want it to change into a new letter by input the number value it has to cycle the alphabet forward not backward. Input = 3, then letter "a" becomes "d". The value input must be applied to all char in a string. Can you guys help me?

Comment: You have to show some effort. Edit your post and add some code you have written. SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for homework help but does not include a summary of the work done so far to solve the problem, nor a description of the difficulty encountered in solving it.

Answer (score 0):

Each character of a keyboard has an ASCII number (it means, an integer related with that character). So if you want to do your task, you should start by [that](http://www.asciitable.com/). Use an `int` type and convert it later into `char` type via casting.

If you have a `string` type, it's so simple such as creating an array of `char` where you will lodge each character of your string, and later you will concatanate each converted character to a new `string` type.

Comment: A Java `string` is a counted sequence of Unicode/UTF-16 code-units: No ASCII involved. (My keyboard sends scan codes to the computer; not character codes. Although all character keys on my keyboard could be represented in the ASCII character set, that's not true for every keyboard and certainly not true of non-character keys. € is quite common on keyboards.)

Comment: You're completetly right @TomBlodget , I didn't think about that. But now I've a question: What would you do in case you want to represent € (for example), via input value as OP is asking? Would it be possible?

Comment: The question is about performing a mapping (an offset, presumably with wraparound) from letters in some sequence onto the same sequence. If the problem space is limited to the Basic Latin Letters then modulo arithmetic would work, after accounting for upper and lower case. A more generalized mapping could make use of parallel arrays (or strings) because if you are going to arithmetic to manipulate characters you have to add some data related to your problem space that isn't an intrinsic characteristic of UTF-16.

Comment: Thank you a lot @TomBlodget!! :)